# How do I fix this Expected Expression Error?

Tags: c++, project, codeblocks

I am trying to write a code for a project, and in my `if else` statements I want to put that the SWI is greater than or equal to 305 and less than or equal to 395. How would I place those limitations in the code? I tried using `<=` and `>=`, but I do not think the placement is correct, and I am confused on how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double T,SWI,W;

    cout << "HELLO USER, PLEASE ENTER THE TEMPERATURE AND WIND SPPED TO PREDICT WEATHER FORECAST";
    cin >> T, W;

    SWI = 150*log10(T-49)+0.41*W+125*W/T;

    if (SWI < 305);{

        cout << "There is a low risk of severe thunderstorms.\n";
        cout << "However, still remain indoors and keep dry until the storm passes\n";

    }else if (SWI >= 305,SWI <= 395); {

        cout<< "Severe thunderstorms possible.\n";
        cout << "Please remain indoors and expect turbulant winds.\n";

    }else if(SWI > 395);{

        cout << "Severe thunderstorms imminent.\n";
        cout << "Stay off the roads and avoid any tall trees, possibility of tornadoes suspected.\n";
    }


    return 0;
} // end program
```

Comment: 1. Remove `;` after if(...). 2. change , in second `else if` to `&&`

Comment: Remove the `#include` from before `using namespace std;`. Or remove the `using namespace std;` altogether and start using `std::`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many syntactic errors. Corrected version below.

also you might need to consider a check on `T`. It must be `>49` else the log function gets a `-ve`  input.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    double T,SWI,W;

    cout << "HELLO USER, PLEASE ENTER THE TEMPERATURE AND WIND SPEED TO PREDICT WEATHER FORECAST";
    cin >> T;
    cin >> W;

    SWI = (150*log10(T-49))+(0.41*W)+(125*W/T);

    if (SWI < 305){

        cout << "There is a low risk of severe thunderstorms.\n";
        cout << "However, still remain indoors and keep dry until the storm passes\n";

    }else if (SWI <= 395) {

        cout<< "Severe thunderstorms possible.\n";
        cout << "Please remain indoors and expect turbulent winds.\n";

    }else {

        cout << "Severe thunderstorms imminent.\n";
        cout << "Stay off the roads and avoid any tall trees, possibility of tornadoes suspected.\n";
    }


    return 0;
} // end program
```

Comment: For a trial I input 80 70 when asked for temperature and wind speed. This is what I got: HELLO USER, PLEASE ENTER THE TEMPERATURE (FROM 50F T0 100F) AND WIND SPPED (FROM 50MPH TO 120MPH) TO PREDICT WEATHER FORECAST80 70
The Sweat Index (SWI) is 223.704 There is a low risk of severe thunderstorms.
However, still remain indoors and keep dry until the storm passes                   The answer is apparently supposed to be 340.079 when I checked with a calculator.

Comment: Check now.. its correct .

I changed it to 
    cin >> T;
    cin >> W;

I got 361.779254075141
as hand calculated.
(150*log10(80-49))+(0.41*70)+(125*70/80)
361.779254075141

Comment: accept it as answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntactics errors. you should have something like:

```
if (SWI< 305){ //remove ; in every if and else

cout<< "There is a low risk of severe thunderstorms.\n"; 
cout << "However, still remain indoors and keep dry until the storm passes\n";

}else if (SWI<=395) { // if the execution falls in here is because SWI>=305

cout<< "Severe thunderstorms possible.\n";
cout << "Please remain indoors and expect turbulant winds.\n";

}else if(SWI > 395){

cout<< "Severe thunderstorms imminent.\n";
cout << "Stay off the roads and avoid any tall trees, possibility of tornadoes suspected.\n"; }

return 0; }
```

Comment: My formula is wrong as well apparently, it won't give the right answer after I checked with a calculator. Any changes?

Comment: which number did you try? Even the if(SWI > 395) is useless. I don't know what this formula is for.

Comment: In the cin, T is temperature and W is wind velocity. The formula is for the SWEAT Index. If the index value of SWI is below 305 then report Non-severe thunderstorms are possible, If the index value is
305 to 395 report severe thunderstorms are possible And if it is >395 report Severe thunderstorms, including tornados are likely.